# MATLAB: Input: ingredients, Output: Recipes

Tags: matlab

I want to use Matlab to help me decide what to make for dinner.

The user is requested to input the ingredients he or she has at home, lets say ingredients a, b, c and d. The program then returns the recipes that doesn't require more ingredients or the recipes that requires least additional ingredients to make in ascending order. There should probably be some limitation of how many recipes the program shows. I mostly need some help getting started with how the program chooses the combination of ingredients.

I'm thinking of assigning all the ingredients a variable.

- ingredient1 = a
- ingredient2 = b
- ingredient3 = c
- recipe1 = abc
- recipe2 = abcd

But how do I get the program to return the recipes that includes most inputted ingredients but also least additional ingredients in the right order?

I always have a problem being creative with the ingredients I have home. Yes, there is services for this on the internet but I want to be able to use my own recipes.

Example:

Ingredients owned: a, b, c and d

Possible recipes:

1. xx (no additional ingredients required)
2. xy (1 additional ingredients required)
3. xz (2 additional ingredients required)
4. yx (3 additional ingredients required)
5. yy (4 additional ingredients required)

Do you guys have any ideas that could steer me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The basic concept is like this website: http://www.supercook.com

Comment: How is your recipes database structured then?

Comment: Of course you can do that with matlab, but why aren't you using a DBMS?

Comment: You read my profile and wanted to try eh! Good job.

Comment: @Lamar obchardon is correct.  Basically... why aren't you using some sort of database technology to do this for you? This kind of problem is exactly what they're designed for.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Lets expand it for linux users: `sudo dinner`

Answer (score 1):

One way you can go is to create struct array of recipes with structures

```
Recipe(ii).MandatoryIngredients={ingredient1;ingredient2;...}
Recipe(ii).OptionalIngredients={ingredient1;ingedient2;...}
Recipe(ii).Procedure={'Step1';'Step2'}
Recipe(ii).Tools={'Tool1';'Tool2'}
```

Then in a function `recommendMe(IN)` defined as:

```
function[RecipeList]=recommendMe(varargin)
```

you can look for ingredients in `Recipe.MandatoryIngredients` and/or `Recipe.OptionalIngrediens` and decide.

Comment: You should write and post code for input `recommendMe(ingredients,<preferences>,)` with preferences like `persons`, `avoid`, `type`, `style`, `serving`, etc...